# How to split and clean up a imported Name field

Tags: c#, .net

I recently imported an excel sheet into `SSMS 2012` and am working with the imported table in an ASP.NET WebForms page.

I'm taking the contents of the imported table and putting them into a permenant table using C#.

As of right now I have a fullname field with some of the following examples:

```
Row 1: John Doe/Jane Doe -- Issues Here (Issue 1)
Row 2: Joe Shmoe
Row 3: Vince Carter
Row 4: Ti m Curry -- Issues here (Issue 2)
```

I don't know enough about c# to account for multiple names like in issue 1. I also am not sure if I need to `Trim` my names before splitting them.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
foreach (DataRow drItem in dtTable.Rows)
            {
                var tempEmployee= drItem["tempEmployee"].ToString();
                var fullName = tempEmployee.Split(' ');
                var firstName = fullName[0];
                var lastName = fullName[1];
```

The code above works fine for `Joe Schmoe` and `Vince Carter`. However for issue 1 my results are:

```
firstName = John
lastName = Doe/Jane  Doe
```

For issue 2 I get:

```
firstName = Ti
lastName = m Curry
```

Comment: Row #4 is just bad data.  The last name in your example should just be 'm', not 'm Curry'.  Row #1 would require to first look for a slash character and split on that before splitting on the space character.

Comment: What if some names genuinely include a middle name.  Eg, John Alan Doe?  How should that be handled?

Comment: And what do you do for names with parts that are not first or last names, like Antonie van Leeuwenhoek? Or Portuguese names with many name parts?

Comment: I think the issues you are facing here is not down to bad data. They are examples that are completely valid and you need to consider these. Read this: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: try doing your split with known multiple delimiters ..and write code to check for multiple spaces this is very do able`Split on ' ', '/'`

Comment: You don't have a programming problem, so this is off-topic. You need to go back to the drawing board and decide what you want to do with data like this. Once you decided that, you can turn your rules into code. If you have a problem with the latter, you can try to ask a question again. All that will happen now is that people are going to guess how to process this data, which isn't helpful for anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that there would be a solution for Issue 2. It would likely take a person to interpret "Ti m" as a typo for "Tim" rather than first name "Ti" and middle initial "m". In this case there's nothing better than a good old fashioned manual cleanup effort after importing the data.

As for Issue 1, you might try splitting on '/' and then doing the name split on each piece you find `foreach (string s in original.Split('/')) { SplitTheName(s); }`.

Any other similar multi-name separators (;, |, whatever) could be treated similarly. Also, if you do `original.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`, you don't need to worry about trimming first because leading and trailing spaces would be split at but discarded.

One trick we use is to look to see if there's a comma in the string, and if so split on the comma and treat it as last-name-first. Otherwise, split on spaces and do first-name-first.

Answer (score 0):

Without using regular expressions to solve the problem (which I'm not sure how to do) and given the criteria you've outlined, you can try the following:

```
foreach(DataRow row in dtTable.Rows)
{
    var employee = row["tempEmployee"].ToString();
    var names = employee.Spit('/'); // solves issue 1
    foreach(var name in names)
    {
        var nameParts = name.Split(' ');
        string first = nameParts.TakeWhile(p => p != nameParts.Last())
                                .Aggregate((a, b) => string.Format("{0} {1}", a, b));
        string last = nameParts.Last();
    }
}
```

This will produce multiple names if you have a `'/'` character in the row. The first name will be all parts of the entry before the last `' '` character and the last name will be everything after the last `' '` character. So your input data would map as follows:

> Row 1: John Doe/Jane Doe
>
> ```
> First: John, Last: Doe
> First: Jane, Last: Doe
> ```
>
> Row 2: Joe Shmoe
>
> ```
> First: Joe, Last: Shmoe
> ```
>
> Row 3: Vince Carter
>
> ```
> First: Vince, Last: Carter
> ```
>
> Row 4: Ti m Curry
>
> ```
> First: Ti m, Last: Curry
> ```

Comment: It might be a good idea to add `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntires` to the `Split`-call.